# virtual basic application registry

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i have made a windows application with a build in button with using visual studio as my application maker and virtual basic as my language.

i need help making the button change a registry folder in the hive due to one of our program that we got has a bug and the folder is miss named.. 
`[Hkey_local_user\software\microsoft\(ERX)`. It needs to be ETRX

i know how to change it manually but cant be doing this to all 68 computers ,that is a big no-no and will take a long time.

can someone make me a blueprint on how i need to make this am not much of a programmer type plus no link helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to sound lazy or unhelpful, but this link will explain it clearer and faster!:)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5b22e94c-37a9-4be5-ad55-3d9229220194/how-to-use-add-read-change-delete-registry-keys-with-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: thank you for the link , i read it but it doesnt tell me what im looking for,,,it tells me on how to change a key valume that exist or how to modify it...im looking for how to modify a folder not the content in which it has inside